# Compare Depth first branch and bound and IDA* search algorithm

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I want to compare and know precise differences between depth first branch and bound and IDA* algorithms. I browsed the internet but i am unable to find clear explanations. Please help!

Comment: -1 This question is not suited for StackOverflow. Try asking it on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ . Btw the key difference is that one uses heuristics and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

IDA* does a f-cost limited depth-first search, pruning paths that are more expensive (using the lower-bound heuristic) than the *current cost bound*. It gradually increases the bound until a solution is found.

DFBnB searches through a tree keeping track of the best solution found thus far, gradually decreasing the cost of the best solution until it is optimal. DFBnB also uses a lower-bound heuristic to prune any paths that are more expensive than the *current best solution*.

Some algorithms, like Budgeted Tree Search, do both types of pruning - using both current cost bounds and the best found solution thus far.